# Check what modules are in a GRUB standalone image without booting?

Tags: grub2, grub

Is there a reasonably simple way to figure out what modules are inside a GRUB standalone image without booting it?

Comment: The [bootinfoscript](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (packaged as `boot-info-script` in Debian and related distributions) can analyze an installed GRUB bootloader on disk. But it looks like it would need modifications for analyzing a standalone image. The function `grub2_info` within the script handles the GRUB analysis part, and it's not exactly simple.

Comment: @telcoM: Interesting, thanks for the pointer!